# Magento: I need Discount Coupon Code Field on Product Detail Page

Tags: magento, discount

I have seen examples and workaround here and there but they doesn't seems to be working in my case. I was thinking if there is any extension or chunk of code that might make it work.
I need discount coupon field to apply discount on any particular product.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Asking for an extension or code is off-topic. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem you are having correctly, you are wanting to apply a **shopping cart price rule** on the product detail page.

If that's the case, there are several factors that come into play. The easiest answer to this is, they have to be applied in the shopping cart. Customer group, region, product type, quantity can all have an effect on if the rule is allowed or not. I do not know of any extensions that allow what you want to do, it could be done with custom development.

One way might be using the URL to contain the coupon code, displaying the product with the coupon code affecting the product and then forcing the customer to login when adding to cart and then applying the code. It would be a significant chunk of work to implement though.

I hope this helps